# Does it make sense to slice a queue into several sharding queues in RabbitMQ when messages are massive

Tags: rabbitmq

When I look into the design in my new company's push applications backed by RabbitMQ, I find that we have some queues which have millions or even hundred million messages to send to for one push task.  Say the queue name is named PUSH_QUEUE

I wonder if I can benefit from the design that I split the queue into several pieces and why:

```
PUSH_QUEUE_1
PUSH_QUEUE_2
PUSH_QUEUE_3
PUSH_QUEUE_4
PUSH_QUEUE_5
```

and producer will send to this sharding queue by robin round, consumer subscribe all the queues.

We don't specify any exchange but the default one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you: [RabbitMQ-Sharding](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding).